# Disputed flag on question relating to stealing software

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, low-quality-posts, disputed-flags

[Someone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18864822/814064) is asking advice on stealing Adobe software.

> Autodesk xforce 2013 keygen tried to read from 0x00000000. And I did
>   reached activation screen. Please help!

When I read about disputed flags it said it means that the post can be fixed.

I don't think that applies in this case.

Comment: What was your flag?

Comment: Very low quality.

Comment: Don't worry, the Meta effect will have it dealt with in no time.

Comment: I would not have declined that flag. I think it's appropriate in this case. If it got handled by a moderator, I wonder if there were on or more other but invalid flags on the question.

Comment: What flag should have been used? I'm curious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very low quality flags also get dumped into the Low Quality Posts queue, which is [where it got reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/2949575). The person who reviewed the post selected that the question looked good, and that automatically dismissed your flag as disputed.

Comment: Another robo reviewer.